# NUnit and ability to ignore failed test without exception

Tags: c#, exception, automated-tests, nunit, assertions

I'm working on a project where I have to use something like soft assertion in NUnit in C#.
I need to implement a feature which says that if a test failed, go to the next test without showing exception but note that this test was failed. 
I know that it's inadvisable to use multiple asserts but it's necessary because I got a form where f.e field with surname can fail but next tests are independent and should still run.

```
public class SoftAssertionTest
{
    public static void AreEqual(object expected, object actual)
    {
        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Catch exception but remember that test failed and got to the 
            //next
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result is that all tests run without exceptions but finally result show Fail status.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public static void Test()
    {
        SoftAssertionTest.AreEqual(1, 2);
        SoftAssertionTest.AreEqual(3, 4);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why can't you just use two different test methods for the different asserts?  If they are independent they should be in separate `[Test]` methods

Comment: I quite new to this topic but as I know, I can't use different test methods because all test are running in BDD and that's why I need to find solution where exceptions are ignored while tests are running but result after performing test show "ok whole test just ended but we got fail just in this point"

Comment: What does BDD stand for?

Comment: Behavior-driven development - bdd combines Test Driven Development and User Acceptance Test. For example, we have a step in BDD like: "user press button" and under this sentence, there is method written in f.e C#. Easy to read and write for analytics and users.

Comment: You can change`AreEqual` from static to instance method then add a some `string/StringBuilder` field to `SoftAssertionTest` where you will log that the test is failed. And in the end of the test you will retrieve this `string/StringBuilder`. By the way, you should catch `AssertionException`, not `Exception`. So this behavior will be useful when you try, for example, compare a some results that are represented as a tree and you want to compare all nodes anyway, But in your example I think that is redundantly

Comment: Oh, of course, it should be AssertionException I just wrote this from memory and forgot about that. Ok, tomorrow I'll try to do this with stringBuilder. Thank you for your answer :).

Answer (score 1):

NUnit 3 has `Assert.Warn` if you just want to warn on failures and `Assert.Multiple` if you want to run multiple asserts and fail the test if any of the individual asserts fail, but ensure that all of the asserts are run.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SoftAssertion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftAssertion/)

```
      SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

      softAssert.True(false);
      softAssert.False(true);
      softAssert.NotNull(null);

      softAssert.VerifyAll();
```